# How to add dots for ViewPager in Android?

Tags: android, view, paging, customization

I am referring to the following link to create a view Pager for android 2.2

[ViewPager Example Link](http://geekyouup.blogspot.com/2011/07/viewpager-example-from-paug.html)

It worked all fine. But I want show dots below the views I am using. How do I do this?

I am not writing any code here as its same as the one in the link I have shared.

Answer (score 0):

When you are put view inside view pager and view contains dots then you can see dots below views.This is not the part of view pager and view pager is only display views whatever you are provided onInstantiate method called .You can put textview below your exist view and given this view same before to view pager

Comment: Hi Thank you for the information, Can you please share some example of the same with dots as I am completely new in this. Raj

Comment: @Override
 public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) { 
  mposition=position;
  StoryView storyviewInstance=new StoryView(mcontext,mstoryLists,position,awesomePager);
  
  ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view,0);

  return view;

 }

Comment: you are put textview below in your layput and give this layout view in your viewpager